# Rendering Caches not working

Tags: mvc, caching

I have a problem with my HTML cache always being empty when I look at the cache report screens in Sitecore I have done the following:

- Enabled Cacheable and Vary By Data on each rendering in Sitecore (view renderings and controller renderings)
- Ensured that under each site (this is a multisite solution) I've set `cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="25MB"`
- Set `Caching.DisableCacheSizeLimits` to true

Am I missing something as when I hit this page: `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx` I see nothing in my HTML cache for any sites. Also `/sitecore/admin/stats.aspx` shows 0 in the from cache column for everything.

Comment: Is the cacheHtml attribute of your <site> element set to true?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: I'm using 8.1 update 2.

Comment: I'd mentioned I have cacheHtml="true" in all my sites above but it looks like you and Dmytro missed that.

Comment: Where did you enable caching? Directly on the rendering item under /sitecore/content/layout? Or on the renderings in Presentation Details?

Comment: Yeah on each rendering item under /layout/renderings. Caching is not set on the presentation details at all. I was hoping this would mean the layout caching would apply instead. Is this not right?

Comment: @aseabridge Do you have this problem with a fresh Sitecore install?

Comment: @corey I've not tried but I guess I could use SIM to do a brand new install of this version of Sitecore and then turn on html caching and create a simple component in mvc in a new project, drop it in and see what happens. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @aseabridge Exactly. Just trying to pin down whether or not it's a configuration issue with your Sitecore instance.

Comment: @AdamSeabridge did you ever get to the bottom of this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: This may seem stupid, but did you publish your renderings after checking "Cacheable"?

Answer (score 4):

To make HTML cache work:

- Make sure that the `cacheHtml` attribute of your `/configuration/sitecore/sites/site` is set to `true`.
- If you dynamically bind a rendering to a placeholder using layout details, cache settings explicitly defined in layout details will override cache settings defined in the rendering definition item. Make sure that cache settings are either set correctly in the layout details, or that they aren't set at all.
- If you use [**Sitecore Debugger**](https://sdn.sitecore.net/scrapbook/enable%20debug%20mode%20for%20web%20site.aspx), make sure that rendering information is turned off by unchecking the "Information" checkbox in the "Rendering" group in Sitecore Debugger.

Comment: The debugger is a great tool to help see what is going on.

Comment: I've tried all of these things but I'm still not seeing anything being cached. I wonder if Glass is doing something which is affecting this.

Answer (score 0):

My html cache eventually started showing data. It did reset to zero every once and a while. But going into debug (in the tracing section) mode I was able to confirm my renderings were pulling from html cache. The trick was to uncheck the boxes for rendering borders and information.

There's a sample of what cached renderings look like in the tracing section
[link here](https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2017/10/02/measure-if-you-want-to-go-faster/)